# How to restrict AWS access based on region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm following this AWS documentation on how to deny access to AWS resources based on the region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-requested-region.html

This is my IAM policy and when I try to access the account I'm not even able to see resources of regions described in "condition" below. Error when accessing EC2 console for "eu-central-1": `You are not authorized to perform this operation`

My goal is to restrict access to any resource of the regions that are not present in the condition. For example, I want to have full access for "eu-central-1" but not for "ap-northeast-1"

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAccessNotListedRegions",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "cloudfront:*",
                "iam:*",
                "route53:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "eu-central-1",
                        "eu-west-3",
                        "eu-west-2",
                        "eu-west-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Saw that you created a policy that worked. Can I recommend that you post it as an answer? I've deleted mine since it was going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found to my case:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"AllowAccessAllRegionListed",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"*",
         "Resource":"*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "aws:RequestedRegion":[
                  "eu-central-1",
                  "eu-west-3",
                  "eu-west-2",
                  "eu-west-1"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "Sid":"AllowAccessGlobalServices",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "cloudfront:*",
            "iam:*",
            "route53:*"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"DenyAccessNotListedRegionsExceptGlobalServices",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "NotAction":[
            "cloudfront:*",
            "iam:*",
            "route53:*"
         ],
         "Resource":"*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringNotEquals":{
               "aws:RequestedRegion":[
                  "eu-central-1",
                  "eu-west-3",
                  "eu-west-2",
                  "eu-west-1"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```